# Non-integer bases

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

## Description:

A [non-integer representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation) of a number uses non-integer numbers as the bases of a positional numbering system.

e.g. Using the golden ratio (the irrational number 1 + √5/2 ≈ 1.61803399 symbolized by the Greek letter φ) as its base, the numbers `1` to `10` can be written:

```
Decimal Powers of φ             Base φ
1       φ0                      1    
2       φ1 + φ−2                10.01 
3       φ2 + φ−2                100.01  
4       φ2 + φ0 + φ−2           101.01  
5       φ3 + φ−1 + φ−4          1000.1001
6       φ3 + φ1 + φ−4           1010.0001
7       φ4 + φ−4                10000.0001
8       φ4 + φ0 + φ−4           10001.0001
9       φ4 + φ1 + φ−2 + φ−4     10010.0101
10      φ4 + φ2 + φ−2 + φ−4     10100.0101
```

Note that just as with any base-n system, numbers with a terminating representation have an alternative recurring representation. In base-10, this relies on the observation that 0.999...=1. In base-φ, the numeral 0.1010101... can be seen to be equal to 1 in several ways:

Conversion to nonstandard form: 1 = 0.11φ = 0.1011φ = 0.101011φ = ... = 0.10101010....φ

One representation in a non-integer base can be found using the [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).

## Challenge:

Given a number `n`, a non-integer real base `b` (`1 < b < 10`, **since, as @xnor pointed out in comments, representation in current format would be nonsensical**), and decimal places `l`, output a non-integer representation of `n` in base `b` to `l` decimal places.

## Test Cases:

```
n=10, b=(1 + Sqrt[5])/2, l=5,     ->     10100.01010
n=10, b=E, l=5,                   ->     102.11201
n=10, b=Pi, l=5,                  ->     100.01022
n=10, b=1.2, l=14,                ->     1000000000001.00000000000001
n=10^4, b=Sqrt[2], l=12,          ->     100001000010010000010000100.000000000001
```

Note any valid representation is allowed. e.g.

```
n=450, b=E, l=6,     ->     222010.221120
```

or

```
n=450, b=E, l=6,     ->     1002020.211202
```

## Prohibitions:

Calling [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12+base+E) or any other external computational site is disallowed. Standard loopholes apply. This is Code Golf, so shortest code wins.

Comment: Can our output be two lists, one of digits and one of decimal places, rather than a string?

Comment: @notjagan yes that's fine

Comment: For this to be able to be solved in any language not called Mathematica, you're going to need to define every notation you will use for `b`. Currently you use `()`, `/`, `Sqrt[]`, `E`, and `Pi`. What else do we need to recognize?

Comment: @StepHen It doesn't matter what your chosen language *doesn't* recognise - as long as input and output agree, and `b` takes non-integer inputs (e.g. `b=1.123468574` or `b=2/5`), that's fine.

Comment: @martin non-integer inputs in _what form_? Can there be `sin`? `mod`? `floor`? Is `b` always given as a rational approximation of the input? This is missing a clear input spec at the moment...

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix as long as `b` is not an integer, it can be in any form. The code should really work with integers too (though `Sin[x]` wouldn't satisfy `b` > 1).

Comment: @martin I believe he means whether we need to deal with an input of `"sin(1+sqrt(5))"`, i.e. whether we need to evaluate those expressions.

Comment: What @LeakyNun said.

Comment: @LeakyNun Apart from the fact that `sin(1+sqrt(5))` wouldn't satisfy `b` > 1, no, there is no limiting criteria that input must be able to handle a certain input. A simple decimal input is acceptable.

Comment: Should we output the greedy choice of representation, or is that just one option?

Comment: @xnor that's just one option

Comment: @martin Can the digits be negative numbers? Or, what if they are above 9?  And I take it the digits must be integers?

Comment: @xnor No, digits can't be negative, and yes the digits must be integers. Digits oiver 9 do present a problem - didn't think of that! - Will add in that bases should be reals from 1 to 10, or would nmean reformatting string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mathematica, 85 bytes

```
(r=RealDigits[#,#2,9#3];k=r[[2]];s=ToString/@r[[1]];""<>s[[;;k]].""<>s[[k+1;;k+#3]])&
```

## Mathematica, 86 bytes

```
(s=TakeDrop@##&@@RealDigits[#,#2,9#3];FromDigits@s[[1]].""<>ToString/@s[[2]][[;;#3]])&
```

**input**

> [450,E,6]

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>151</s> <s>134</s> 121 120 bytes

```python
import math
def f(n,b,l,r=''):
 for i in range(int(math.log(n,b)),-l-1,-1):r+="%i"%(n/b**i)+'.'*(0==i);n%=b**i
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BDoMgEEX3nGJiYmAQrabpxobDaAo6iQKZ0EVPT4vbbt9/eT998h7DvRQ6U@QM55J38XIevApmNYdhKyXOAnxkIKAAvITNKQpZVXc44lZNRNMf/WT6CWfubNNS06pwW7Um7OQgtRqtJXyG1lYmgF1@869WEteWV9NorvfBGXggij@e6BrKFw)

Returns a string of the non-integer base representation. This can probably be golfed more; stay tuned.

---

Special thanks to:

- @LeakyNun for saving 13 bytes!
- @Zacharý for saving 1 byte!

Comment: [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##TcxBCoMwEEDRfU4xCJJMHFuldGPJYZQmOqBJGNJFT5/Wrrp9fH5@ly3FW61B0gHHXDbgIycpVj19gGAiLbSTOK1xUhCSAANHkDmu3nAsZk/rGSFSv/cj9SNO0rmm5aY18bpYy9jpi7ZmcI7xEVt3mgLx5SXfUc1yboIZBwJPcEdU/5T5Z/UD)

Comment: @LeakyNun woah. What's going on in `"%i"%(n/b**i)`? I've not seen syntax like that before.

Comment: It is string formatting. `"%i"` is the string to be formatted, with parameter `n/b**i`

Comment: You can save a single byte by using `import math` then `math.log`.

Comment: @Zacharý good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 47 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{⌽⊃∘⍕¨⍺⍺(↑,'.',↓)⌊(⊣,⍨⍺×1|⊢)⍣(⍺⍺+z)⍨⍵÷⍺*z←⌊⍺⍟⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRz95HXc2POmY86p16aMWj3l1ApPGobaKOup66zqO2yZqPero0HnUt1nnUC5I9PN2w5lHXIs1HvYs1IIq1qzTBUlsPbwfytKoetU0AagHLzQeK1v5PA4n09gFtObTeGGjyo76pwUHOQDLEwzP4/6PeuQpahgqZxQqpcYYKtgqpXHlA9YYGCo@6WxSSgEygJIiZA2SaciVp5CikaeYpKIC0GRoY6RkaGhkYgrWYmGLVY4aux8AICPWMQBqN0O0y1DOCazQ0wdAJB4Z6BsjAEAA)

A dop that takes `n`, `b`, `l` as `⍵` (right arg), `⍺` (left arg), `⍺⍺` (left operand) respectively. Does greedy conversion from the most significant digit.

#### How it works

```apl
{⌽⊃∘⍕¨⍺⍺(↑,'.',↓)⌊(⊣,⍨⍺×1|⊢)⍣(⍺⍺+z)⍨⍵÷⍺*z←⌊⍺⍟⍵}  ⍝ ⍵←n, ⍺←b, ⍺⍺←l

⍵÷⍺*z←⌊⍺⍟⍵  ⍝ Part 1
      ⌊⍺⍟⍵  ⍝ Floor of Log of n with base b
            ⍝ (number of digits above decimal point - 1)
    z←      ⍝ Assign to z
⍵÷⍺*        ⍝ Divide n by b^z, so that floor will give highest digit
            ⍝ Let's say the value is k

(⊣,⍨⍺×1|⊢)⍣(⍺⍺+z)⍨k  ⍝ Part 2
(        )⍣(⍺⍺+z)⍨k  ⍝ Repeat l+z times, using k as both the
                     ⍝ left arg (fixed) and right arg (moving)...
      1|⊢  ⍝ Fractional part of right arg
    ⍺×     ⍝ Multiply b
 ⊣,⍨       ⍝ Append left arg
⍝ The net effect is "prepend next significant digit, keeping fractional part"
⍝ Let's say the resulting array is v

⌽⊃∘⍕¨⍺⍺(↑,'.',↓)⌊v  ⍝ Part 3
                ⌊v  ⍝ Floor each number in v
     ⍺⍺(↑,'.',↓)    ⍝ Insert the decimal point after l digits
 ⊃∘⍕¨               ⍝ Convert each digit to a char
⌽                   ⍝ Reverse, so that the highest digit comes first
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>129</s> <s>123</s> <s>121</s> <s>120</s> 118 bytes (115 + `-lm` compiler flag)

```c
f(n,b,l,i,y,z)double n,b,l,z;{for(i=log(n)/log(b);~i<l;n=fmod(n,z))z=pow(b,i),printf(".%d"+!!~i--,y=n/z);puts("");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LasMwEEX3/oqJS0FDZNkSyUpxd110UegfFL/kCGTZ9YMSh@TT6zo2CU7IXYyQOHMuSrzERDYfBkUsjamhmh5oj2nZxSaD@amXR1XWRIemzIlF/3LEKM96Z6QNVVGm426P2IdV@UtiqpFWtbatIi57Td31anXWnkcPofV7lFXXNsR1UZ6GF20T06UZ7Iqo3bP9m@OMa1BE2hKEowNjFOEBBcJhDc1P3ZItIvggKGxRgu8DD3gQsMvgC/7z@30m7jPxgnEuHuivjyf4RE9uIRY0Z2M73yB9Rt/CWbDMrS7b0PkjYhRwsei8Cq5jtl1v7E52Gv4SZaK8GTxT/AM)

<s>7</s> <s>8</s> 10 bytes shaved off thanks to ceilingcat!